# Gridview display

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I dont know what it is but i'm having all sorts of issues with this gridview.  Below is the code but the issues is the grid is not displaying.  Visibility is set to true and the query does return results.  So I'm asking for another set of eyes to point out what went wrong here.

Thank you

```
        protected void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\levels.mdb";
        DataSet ds;
        using (OleDbConnection myConnString = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            myConnString.ConnectionString = connString;
            using (OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                selectCommand.CommandText = "select * from tblTest";
                selectCommand.Connection = myConnString;
                myConnString.Open();
                using(OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    da.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
                    ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "test");

                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }                    
            }                
        }               
    }//end click event
```

and the gridview

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: it probably has something wrong making it break. Can you also write the gridview code please? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data source should have been:

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["test"];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
```